# NotifyJS returns code instead of alert on success

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an alert on `success` that is returning 
`{ success = true, message = "Registro agregado correctamente." }` 
instead of NotifyJS alert, I've checked syntax and possible errors (against NotifyJs references) and I can't see where is the error or why the script it's ignored.

The following code runs when the validation works and the values are already stored in the database.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AnadirLic(licenciasUsuario lic, string FileUpload)
        {

            using (model1 db = new model1())
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid) { 
                    //IF TRUE THEN DO STUFF
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    //RETURN VALUES TO NOTIFYJS ALERT
                    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Registro agregado correctamente." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

                }
                else
                {
                  //RETURN ERROR
                  return Json(new { success = false, message = "Registro no aagregado, revisar los campos ingresados." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }

            }


        }
```

And the JS form validation and alert is this:

```js
function SubmitForm(form) {

            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);

            var archivo = document.getElementById("FileUpload").Value;
            form.append("FileUpload", archivo);

            if ($(form).valid()) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: form.action,
                    //url: '@Url.Action("AnadirLic","Licencia")/'+ id,
                    data: $(form).serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.success) {
                            Popup.dialog('close');

                            $('#tablaLicencia').DataTable().ajax.reload()

                            //RETURNS CODE
                            $.notify(data.message, {
                                globalPosition: "top center",
                                className: "success",
                            })

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Did you check if browser console gives any javascript errors?

Comment: Yes, in the return the console gets "cleaned". @Adlorem

Comment: DataTable is reloaded? Try to put console.log(data.message) and check what you get.

Comment: Yes, using ajax as soon as the record gets stored the DataTable displays the new row. console.log return this after the return: `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "http://localhost:53737/Licencia/AnadirLic".
Navigated to http://localhost:53737/Licencia/AnadirLic`

Comment: Your code is correct please show your css and js load order.

Comment: @Adlorem Css it's the default on a fresh mvc project and this is the order of the js script `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/notify.js"></script>`

Comment: Does script load before your <script></script> in document? Check your page source.